# Can't use bold, upright Minion Pro font with LuaLaTeX

Tags: fonts, luatex, miktex, fontspec

When trying to use bold Minion Pro, it also turns the font italic. Like with this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Minion Pro}
\begin{document}
\textbf{Bold.}
\end{document}
```

I'm using MiKTeX and LuaLaTeX. The problem doesn't appear with any other font I've tried, or when using XeTeX.

I don't recall this happening a while ago, so it might be related to some update.

Comment: I'm using the prerelease of luaotfload (https://github.com/lualatex/luaotfload/releases) together with miktex and there your example works fine.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I was already using the prerelease luaotfload. Unless there is some more step needed to install it properly or something. But it did resolve an earlier problem.